# Passing " as parameter in text search

Tags: vba, excel

This one seems simple and I am stuck. I have a function in VBA which searches a string and replaced a char with another (kind of like REPLACE function but with some other workings in it)

I call the function as such:

```
NewText = My_Replace(OldText, "sample text", """)
```

This function will look for an occurrence of `"sample text"` and find the first `"` that appears, and remove this piece from the string.

Problem is, how do I pass `"` to the function as this is the other end of the string I am trying to cut.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried passing the ASCII character i.e. replacing `"""` with `Chr(34)`?

Comment: What does the my_replace function look like as it seems that is the piece of code your having a problem with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the double-quote by doubling it within the string.  So you need 6 `"` characters (one to open the string literal, two for the first double-quote, two for the second double-quote, one to close the literal), resulting in

```
NewText = My_Replace(OldText, "sample text", """""")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the var in my function now contains "" instead of ". This will not work. The function looks for the substring starting at "sample text" and ending at " in my example. The "" causes it to fail. I just need to pass a single " as a string var... thanks

Comment: strange, I just did a quick test with excel-2010 vba and it only passed a single quotation mark. hmmm not sure whats going on there.